# Scroll animation of UILabel just like morque

Tags: ios, animation

Need to implement scrolling like animation to UILabel continuously just like marquee(but I need from bottom to top animation)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UILabel` you should use `UITextView`. Keep the user interaction and editable property to false.

Iterate through its subviews and identify the scrollview using kindOfClass. Now using time change the value of content offset (origin.y component) to scroll it from bottom to top.

Comment: Can't you directly access the contentOffset property of a textview? I mean is it necessary to iterate through subview and stuff coz uitextview inherits from uiscrollview. I'm currently not able to test it myself, so asking :)

Comment: @Adithya Yes, you should be able to use it directly. I thought it is inherrited from UIView and not the UIScrollView.